# Get FDQN from url and link it to grafana dashboards data link

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-dashboard

I have a grafana dashboard and I want to extract the url and use it in grafana data links .is there a variable I can use in order to get the url.

Example: I want to extract this https://bingoke.com  and use it in datalinks

[image]

I want to replace localhost with  https://bingoke.com which comes from the url using some variable . not hard coding it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use absolute URL e.g. `https://bingoke.com/?queueId=...`, but relative URL instead e.g. `/?queueId=...`, so browser will use current protocol/domain automatically.

Comment: Yes it works but now on the datalink clicked the url appends /grafana .
eg https://bingoke.com/grafana/queueId=... . I only want when clicked to direct me to https://bingoke.com/queueId=...       but it seems its also appending /grafana .

Comment: @AbrahamLugonzo naive workaround: use path tracing, so `/../?queueId=...`

Comment: @JanGaraj Thanks a lot! Where can I read more about path tracing?